# Rails: Microsoft Graph Webhook - 400 Subscription Validation Request Timed Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microsoft-graph-api

I am having some trouble working with the MicrosoftGraph Webhook. I think that I am not properly returning HTTP response, because when I put a binding.pry into my controller, after making the request it hits the controller.

However, the request seems to timeout before hitting my controller (see stack trace below). Here is my controller code and subscription request code, and stack trace. I really appreciate the help.

```
def self.create_subscription(user)

  callback = Proc.new do |r| 
    r.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{user.outlook_token.access_token}"
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    r.headers['X-AnchorMailbox'] = user.email
  end

  path = 'subscriptions'

  data = {
    changeType: "created, updated",
    notificationUrl: "https://my_url/api/watch/outlookNotification",
    resource: "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
    expirationDateTime:"2017-08-19T06:23:45.9356913Z",
    clientState: "subscription-identifier"
  }

  graph = MicrosoftGraph.new(base_url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0',
                             cached_metadata_file: File.join(MicrosoftGraph::CACHED_METADATA_DIRECTORY, 'metadata_v1.0.xml'),
                             &callback)

  response = graph.service.post(path, data.to_json)
end

def outlook_webhook  
   @token = params[:validationToken]
   head 200, content_type: "text/plain", content_length: 7
   response.body = @token
end
```

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14613ms (ActiveRecord: 478.4ms)
>
> OData::ClientError (400 InvalidRequest: "Subscription validation
>   request timed out." from
>   "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions"):
>   app/models/outlook_wrapper.rb:44:in `create_subscription'
>
>   app/controllers/business/messages_controller.rb:18:in`index'
>
> Rendered
>   /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (7.9ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.9ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
>   (3.8ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
>   (176.2ms)
>
> Started POST
>   "/api/watch/outlookNotification?validationToken=YTJhMTk5MDQtYjdmOC00ZjYxLWIzOGEtMDczM2FjMTAxZTBj"
>   for 52.161.110.176 at 2017-08-23 12:29:05 -0400 Processing by
>   InboundEmailsController#outlook_webhook as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"validationToken"=>"YTJhMTk5MDQtYjdmOC00ZjYxLWIzOGEtMDczM2FjMTAxZTBj"}
>   Completed 200 OK in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 0):

A Content-Length of 7 is not large enough to accommodate the validation token.

As far as the request timing out, when testing locally, is `notificationUrl` a publicly accessible URL? If you're using something like `http://localhost/api/watch/outlookNotification`, then Microsoft will not know how to access your webhook since `localhost` is not a publicly accessible host.

Even if you do provide a publicly accessible host, you'll still need to poke a hole in your firewall. My suggestion is to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) when testing locally and use an environment variable to set the host.

Run `ngrok http 3000` in a console and it will give you a URL that looks something like `https://d83375e5.ngrok.io`. While `ngrok` is running, it will forward HTTP and HTTPS requests from `d83375e5.ngrok.io` to your computer on port `3000`.

If you use a notificationUrl like `https://${ENV['WEBHOOK_HOST']}/api/watch/outlookNotification`, then in development, set the environment variable `WEBHOOK_HOST` to the host provided by `ngrok`. In production, you don't need to run `ngrok`; just set `WEBHOOK_HOST` to the publicly accessible host for your server.

Comment: Jordan, thanks for the answer, I have since changed that. I have the solution working in production. However, my localhost server still times out, before returning a response. Do you have any ideas why my localhost would not be responding quickly enough?

Comment: Hi Jordan, sorry I should have specified, that I am using Ngrok to tunnell my application already. I apologize. I really do not understand why it is not working. I have even updated my ram, cleaned up my comp to improve performance so I really dont know...

Comment: Does the ngrok inspector show that Microsoft is hitting your ngrok instance?

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to the party, but I ran into this same issue. The development environment in rails blocks multiple requests which is why you are getting a timeout. Since you are waiting for a response from the post while Graph is blasting a request back, the request will be blocked until you receive a response from your first post.

As it seems you have discovered, when running in prod this is not an issue as the production environment settings do not block multiple requests.